# How to delete number of rows if cell meets criteria excel vba

Tags: excel, rows

Im looking for a way to delete a total of 6 rows if a cell (C20) in the first of those 6 rows contains "#REF!". Here's what i have so far :

```
Sub Button7_Click()

Dim srchRng As Range

Worksheets("Summary").Activate

ActiveWindow.DisplayFormulas = False


Set srchRng = Range("C20:C300")

Dim c As Range
For Each c In srchRng
If c.Formula = "=#REF!" Then
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Aug").Columns(2).SpecialCells(xlFormulas,     xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete
              
    Exit For
End If
Next

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld it will only delete one row. I am looing to delete the next 5 rows as well starting from the first row with the cell #REF!

Comment: Take a look at the `Resize` property.  Might have to change your iteration to go from the bottom up, though, in case your pointer gets confused.

Comment: I will add a screenshot

Comment: So if C20.formula = #Ref! then delete C20 + 6 rows

Comment: And what happened when you used the `.Resize` property?

Comment: Im sorry where do i use the .Resize property ?

Comment: You use it to resize the range you are trying to delete.  Read the help topic for it first.

Comment: Oh ok i will check. So something like this If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "none" Then
        .Cells(i - 1, 1).Resize(27, 1).EntireRow.Delete

Comment: Sure, if you want to delete 27 rows.  READ help for resize again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution to my question :

```
Sub Button7_Click()

Dim r As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Worksheets("Summary").Activate

 '   To Loop through rows backwards
   For r = 300 To 20 Step -1
 '     To Check the formula in column C
      If Cells(r, "C").Formula = "=#REF!" Then
 '         To Delete row and 5 rows under it
        Rows(r & ":" & r + 5).Delete
    End If
 Next r

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Done!"

End Sub
```

You could also replace this line:

```
       Rows(r & ":" & r + 5).Delete
```

with something like this:

```
       Cells(r, "C").Resize(6, 1).EntireRow.Delete
```